# CodeIgniter Ion Auth 2 Login AND Registration on single page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to run Ion Auth 2 login form and register user form on a single page (my home page), but no success. I tried to dublicate the code from create_account() function inside the login() function, but it doesnt work. I searched a lot for such an example, but nothing found for the two forms on one page. Can someone give me an advise or refference? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is rather easy. You have two forms, and each of the forms is directed at a different controller function via the `action` attribute of the form. Those controller functions (let's call them `login` and `register` set flash  messages and redirect back to the `index` auth controller (e.g. your homepage with the login and create user forms).

Here is an example using some of the code from https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/controllers/Auth.php

```
<?php

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
            // user logged in, redirect them to the dashboard
            redirect('dashboard');
        }
    }

    /**
     * this page, /auth/ will have your forms and will
     * submit to login() and  register()
     * 
     * login form action: /auth/login
     * create account form action: /auth/register
     */
    public function index() {
        $data['message'] = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $this->load->view('login_and_create_user', $data);
    }

    public function login() {
        // validate form input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', str_replace(':', '', $this->lang->line('login_identity_label')), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', str_replace(':', '', $this->lang->line('login_password_label')), 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            // check to see if the user is logging in
            // check for "remember me"
            $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

            if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
                // if login is successful, redirect to dashboard
                redirect('dashboard');
            } else {
                // login failed
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            }
        } else {
            // form validation failed, redirect to auth with validation errors
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', validation_errors());
        }
        redirect('auth'); // redirect them back to the login/create user page
    }

    public function register() {
        // same thing here for create logic
        // validate, db, redirect
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but at my index page I do not have access to the errors validations messages for both forms

Comment: That's what the flash messages are for